# How to make simple horizontal photo gallery with iOS5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, gallery, scrollview

I would like to make a VERY simple photo gallery that displays 1 image at a time, that you swipe left or right to see the image. This gallery will have 4-6 images max. It doesn't need any fancy effects or zooming etc.

I tried rotating a scrollView 90 degrees with images, but the scroll speed is too fast, if you swipe left you should only move 1 image at a time, and if you're in mid swipe then let go, the scroll view should auto scroll to the nearest full image/cell. Maybe if someone could help me with just those to things that would be nice. I don't want to use three20, as it's very complicated and has a lot of things I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rotate the scroll view. Just set the content size to be wider then the screen. To make it stop at every image, you have to use **paging**. Set `pagingEnabled` to `YES` and the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view’s bounds when the user scrolls.

Comment: Ok great! last thing, how can I keep track of which cell there on without them actually clicking a cell, I have a save button at the top which should save the photo of the cell their currently on

Comment: You have to calculate the index yourself using the scroll view's content offset. Something like `roundf(yOffset / contentWidth)`.

Comment: ok the only thing I still don't get is how to set the content size to be wider then the screen

Comment: `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfImages * widthOfScreen, scrollView.bounds.size.height);`

Comment: Ok well I have 3 images now, the 1st shows up, but how do I add the other images to the content view. Scrollview doesn't indexes/cells like tables do.